# systematic linear sampling

Tags: sampling

I would like to see if there is an influence of the age variable on different medical indicators.
To find out I have extracted 60 individuals from a large dataset, each of them have a different progressive age from 20 to 80 years.
So for example these are my data:

| subject | age |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 20 |
| 2 | 21 |
| 3 | 22 |
| .. | .. |
| 59 | 79 |
| 60 | 80 |

In this way I can then split the data into three groups and create a new variable: young - adults - old

Am I using the right procedure?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: For studying the relationship between age and other variables you might have, this strikes me as a plausible approach, yet one that is likely to be particularly poor compared to standard regression techniques that use all the variables and don't bin them into such coarse groups.